# SQL Server minus query gives issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare two table's values for difference (I suspect for two **TankSystemIds** containing same data)

My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] 
WHERE hdTankSystemId = 2782

MINUS

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] 
WHERE hdTankSystemId = 2380
```

But I get an error about syntax issues:

> Incorrect syntax near 'minus'

But this is right[1]?
[1] https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Comment: use "INTERSECT" replace "minus" ?

Comment: I tried intersect , but it doesnt return any single row for different ids, where it has to//    select * FROM [dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] where hdTankSystemId =2381
  INTERSECT
    select * FROM [dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] where hdTankSystemId =2382//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted in your link.

> For databases such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, use the EXCEPT operator to perform this type of query.

For your case, it seems like you are looking for duplicated data, intersect should be used instead.

Also, INTERSECT statement like

```
SELECT
    EXPRESSION_1, EXPRESSION_2, ..., EXPRESSION_N
FROM
    TABLE_A
INTERSECT
SELECT
    EXPRESSION_1, EXPRESSION_2, ..., EXPRESSION_N
FROM
    TABLE_B
```

can be written as

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_1, TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_2, ..., TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_N
FROM
    TABLE_A
INNER JOIN
    TABLE_B
ON
    TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_1 = TABLE_B.EXPRESSION_1
AND TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_2 = TABLE_B.EXPRESSION_2
.
.
.
AMD TABLE_A.EXPRESSION_N = TABLE_B.EXPRESSION_N
```

If you use select * from the same table with a different where condition then intersect them, you are not going to get any rows as they have different value on the specific column used in where condition.

Comment: Thnaks a lot..I dint notice..But intersect works wrong?

Comment: I tried intersect , but it doesnt return any single row for different ids, where it has to/ //   select * FROM [dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] where hdTankSystemId =2381
  INTERSECT
    select * FROM dbo].[vwRawSaleTransaction] where hdTankSystemId =2382//

Comment: Try "EXCEPT"... or you could do an exclusion join, which would work on most any database type.

Comment: Because their hdTankSystemId are different. Instead of Select *, replace * with the necessary columns instead. @Ratha

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I tried except..returns wrong result. ANy sample for exclusion join?

Comment: The general pattern is `TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON ... WHERE TableB.IDColumn IS NULL`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks a lot.I understood my Mistake, I selected HdTanksystemid too . That is why Result was wrong.  Except works for me.(returns 0 rows, i expected result) INTERSECT returns, all rows.